# Why is Rasa core training unstable?

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core

When I train the Rasa core, the training accuracy fluctuates a lot. At one run, it can go up to 95%, then I restart over and re-train once, it goes down to 75%. Is this normal? What's the reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the pipeline, number of stories, augmentation, number of epochs and other hyperparameters, it can happen. Usually, it depends on these details and it is hard to tell without knowing them.